# PDF file font not as like source html

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, pdf-generation

I am facing little issue in my php code.I am sending a pdf file in attachment and pdf file is created dynamically with html and having external css import statement for some font. I have setup the content type and header information and i am getting the pdf as attachment but not getting the proper font as like html i used. Can anyone suggest the solution for this?

Comment: which library are you using to create PDF file?

Comment: I am using http://phptopdf.com for pdf creation.

Comment: Are there any error logs ? For example 404 or reference error to the font file required ?

Answer (score 0):

Fonts are embedded in PDF's.  It is up to your code to embed the font.  A good server-side program for PDF generation is PDFLib but they charge for a license.